# Error -2147352571 Type Mismatch: cannot coerce parameter value

Tags: forms, ms-access, scripting

I am struggling with the above error when trying to write the Visual Basic code for a 2010 Access Form. I am trying to get ensure that the associate and the Team Lead get the same email. When I first wrote the code, it worked initially. I have since added an "issue date" to the form, but not to the email. I attempted to add the issue date to the Script, but that did not work. I have since removed both the issue date from the form and the script.  Any help would appreciated:

```
Private Sub cmdEmail_Click()
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMailItem As Object
Const olMailItem As Integer = 0
 Dim objMailItem1 As Object
 Const olMailItem1 As Integer = 0
 Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set objMailItem = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 Set objMailItem1 = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem1)

 Dim strPathAttach As String
 On Error GoTo err_Error_handler
 'set receipient, you can use a DLookup() to retrieve your associate Email address
 objMailItem.To = DLookup("Email_ID", "dbo_Noble_Associates", "[Fullname]='" & Me.cboAssociate & "'")
 objMailItem1.To = DLookup("Email_ID", "dbo_TeamLeads$", "[Fullname]='" & Me.txtTeamLead & "'")
 'set subject with text and Form values
 objMailItem.Subject = "Attendance Violation " & Me.cboAssociate
 objMailItem1.Subject = "Attendance Violation " & Me.cboAssociate
 'set body content with text and Form values etc.
 objMailItem.htmlBody = "Date of Occurrence: " & Format(Me.Occurrence_Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")     & "<br>" & "Attendance Points: " & Me.CboType & "<br>" & "Total Points: " & Me.txtTotalpoints     & "<br>" & "Notes: " & Me.txtNotes
 objMailItem1.htmlBody = "Date of Occurrence: " & Format(Me.Occurrence_Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")     & "<br>" & "Attendance Points: " & Me.CboType & "<br>" & "Total Points: " & Me.txtTotalpoints & "<br>" & "Notes: " & Me.txtNotes

 ' display email
 ' objMailItem.Display
 ' sending mail automaticly
 objMailItem.Send
 objMailItem1.Send
 Set objOutlook = Nothing
 Set objMailItem = Nothing
 Set objMailItem1 = Nothing

 exit_Error_handler:
 On Error Resume Next
 Set objOutlook = Nothing
 Set objMailItem = Nothing
 Set objMailItem1 = Nothing

 Exit Sub

 err_Error_handler:
 Select Case Err.Number
 'trap error 287
 Case 287
 MsgBox "Canceled by user.", vbInformation
 Case Else
 MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
 End Select
 Resume exit_Error_handler
 End Sub
 Private Sub CheckEmail_Click()
 End Sub
 Private Sub cmdSaveandNew_Click()
 If Me.txtOccurrence_Date & "" = "" Then
 MsgBox "Please enter the date."
 Me.txtOccurrence_Date.SetFocus
 Exit Sub
 ElseIf Me.cboAssociate & "" = "" Then
 MsgBox "Please select the associate's name."
 Me.cboAssociate.SetFocus
 Exit Sub
 ElseIf Me.txtPoints & "" = "" Then
 MsgBox "Please enter the number of Points."
 Me.txtPoints.SetFocus
 Exit Sub
 End If

 If Me.CheckEmail = True Then
 cmdEmail_Click
 End If
 DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
 End Sub
 Private Sub cmd_Cancel_Click()
 Me.Undo
 DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

 End Sub
 Private Sub cboassociate_AfterUpdate()
 Me.txtTeamLead.Value = Me.cboAssociate.Column(1)
 End Sub
 Private Sub cboFullname_AfterUpdate()
 Me.txtCurrentpoints.Value = Me.cbofullname.Column(1)
 End Sub

 Private Sub CboType_AfterUpdate()
 Me.txtPoints.Value = Me.CboType.Column(1)
 End Sub
```

I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Is Occurrence_Date the same as the issue date you refer to?  Could you post just the section of code you added to the script, if above is the working code?

Comment: The Occurrence_Date is not the same as the issue date. This is the original code that was working. The Issue Date has been removed. This is the code that is not working now. I have another form that has the same mirrored code, the only change is "dbo_Noble_Associates" in the dlookup.

Comment: Oh I see.  What happens when you try Me.cboAssociate.Value?  I always thought you had to specify the Value property in VBA for comboboxes.

Comment: I assume that you are saying at each time a Me.cbo comes up, to change it to Me.cbo####.Value? Just want to see if that is what you are saying.

Comment: yes, but try the  objMailItem.To line first.  If the combobox has more than one column you have to do something like cbo#.columns(0).value  As the code was working, it's got to be something simple.

Comment: At the risk of asking the obvious... on what line is the error actually raised...?

Comment: @ChrisRolliston The error does not highlight a line. It comes as a compile error and closes the form out. The data saves on the form and writes to the database, but does not send the email.

Comment: @JimmySmith the combobox is a standard combo box with no additional columns. I made the change on objMailItem.to and the same error, but not a new end to the error. "Outlook cannot translate your string". I had a suggestion of removing the copy of the code and go with a CC option. That ended in the same error.

Comment: I'm confused - you've reported a runtime error, not a compile-time one. Do you get a specific line if you comment out `On Error GoTo err_Error_handler`?

Comment: Sorry yes it is a runtime error. I do not get a line error when I click Save and Close. When I check the Email box on my form, the string is suppose to go back and run the email string. When that starts, I get the runtime error listed above.

Comment: I did notice that Set objMailItem1 = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem1) should be Set objMailItem1 = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)  .  To narrow it down to the error line, try setting a breakpoint on the objMailItem.To and verify that string is populating correctly or just set it within the error handler

Comment: @JimmySmith SO I set the mark at objMailItem.To = DLookup("Email_ID", "dbo_Noble_Associates", "[Fullname]='" & Me.cboAssociate & "'") NO error came about, the code just opened and the line was highlighted.